# Changing Background color for TextView on click in Android using Java

Tags: java, android

In my Android app, I have category titles shown in picture. When I click the title below content will be changed depending upon the category title. At that same time title, the background color should change but other title background colors should remain the same. How to do that in Android Studio using Java?

[image]

Comment: add more code to understand

Comment: my title is a dynamic one

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background colors of your TextViews like this:

```
yourTextViewTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    yourContentTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.yourColor));
                }
            });
```

Comment: App gets crashed

Comment: did you replace the yourTextViewTitle, yourContentTextView and yourColor by your fields ?

Comment: you can edit your question and post some code of what you have already tried so far, so we can understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For every view, there is a setBackgroundColor method

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Comment: my title is a dynamic one

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
...

title1, title2, title3, selectedTitle;

...

title1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    updateTitleBackground(title1);
});

title2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    updateTitleBackground(title2);
});

title3.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    updateTitleBackground(title3);
});

...

private void updateTitleBackground(title) {
    if(selectedTitle != null) {
        selectedTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    selectedTitle = title;
    title.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}

...
```

Comment: my title is a dynamic one... check my answers

Comment: Add some implementation that you have done so far. Otherwise it's hard to provide solution. And I gave you an idea how to achieve this whatever it is dynamic or static

Answer (score 0):

**Here are instruction and code for you to complete your target -**

```
String titleContent1 = "Content 1", titleContent2 = "Content 2", titleContent3 = "Content 3";

textView1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    changeBackgroundColorAndTitle(titleContent1, getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
});


textView2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    changeBackgroundColorAndTitle(titleContent2, getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
});


textView3.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    changeBackgroundColorAndTitle(titleContent3, getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
});

private void changeBackgroundColorAndTitle(String titleContent, int color) {
    selectedTitle = title;
    contentTextView.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
// initialize your views inside your onCreate()
title1 = findViewById("yourtextviewid");
title2 = findViewById("yourtextviewid");
title3 = findViewById("yourtextviewid");

title1.setOnClickListener(this);
title2.setOnClickListener(this);
title3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In your `onClick` method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   if(view ==  title1)
      // here i assumed yourContentView and contenTextview you should use yours.
      yourContentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
      contentTextView.setText("Title1");
   }else if(view ==  title2){
      yourContentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
      contentTextView.setText("Title2");
   }else if(view ==  title3){
      yourContentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
      contentTextView.setText("Title3");
   }
``
```